# download kernel source code : error : Not enough diskspace

Tags: kernel, raspberry-pi

I need to download the source code of raspbian kernel with `rpi-source` command

I receive an error Not enough diskspace (900MB even that my sd card has 8 GB of space.

`ubuntu` shows me two partitions one boot of 58MB and another 2.9GB volume. so where are the 5GB remaining space ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and select the first option `extend Filesystem`.  This will use the entire SD card.